# Missing destructor in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, language-lawyer, destructor

I wrote the following program:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "A ctor" << std::endl;

    }

    ~A() { 
        std::cout << "A dtor" << std::endl;
        try {
            throw std::exception();
        } catch (std::exception &e) {
            std::cout << "Internal exception caught" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        A a;
        throw std::exception();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "External exception caught" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output I expected was:

```
A ctor
A dtor
Internal exception caught
External exception caught
```

And this is what I'm getting in GCC. But when I'm using Visual Studio (version 2013) the output I'm getting is:

```
A ctor
External exception caught
```

What's going on here?

Comment: *"What's going on here?"* - A blunder by the MS compiler design team :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*MSVC2013* is wrong here and *GCC* is right. Unfortunately, I cannot find an appropriate reference from the standard now, but according to [std::uncaught_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception):

> For example, if stack unwinding causes a stack-allocated object to be
> destructed, the destructor for that object could run code that throws
> an exception as long as the exception is caught by some catch block
> before escaping the destructor.

For more details see also *"Throwing during stack unwinding"* section [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/destructors-that-throw/).

Finally, as it is mentioned by @StoryTeller, this behaviour is not reproducible with newer MSVC versions.

---

The closest match in the standard I am able to find is the next (from the N3936 draft):

> 15.1 Throwing an exception [except.throw]
>
> 7. If the exception handling mechanism, after completing the
>    initialization of the exception object but before the activation of a
>    handler for the exception, calls a function that exits via an
>    exception, std::terminate is called.

So, formally, it is perfectly valid to call a function during stack unwinding process (including destructor) which might deal with exception, but if the exception inside such function is not caught by appropriate `catch` block then `std::terminate` must be called.

Comment: @Bathsheba I assume it is UB when an exception is thrown from the destructor during stack unwinding, but while it is *inside* destructor it might be caught without invoking UB.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan - Almost correct. This will just call `std::terminate`. So not undefined, just catastrophic from the standards POV.

Comment: @StoryTeller Good point, as always! In such situation `std::terminate` will be called.

Comment: [Worth noting MSVC2015 prints the same as GCC. This is 100% compiler bug.](http://rextester.com/live/BHLLV60541)

Comment: I'm about to delete my answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller At least it is fixed now :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I've added some wording from the standard draft though I doubt a bit whether it is well applicable to the problem.